Where are enterprise keywords stored?
I have enabled enterprise keywords column on my document library.
When users enter the keywords for the files, then where do these keywords get stored? Is it stored at site level or at library level?

They are stored at the tenant level and periodically (presumably daily) synced to a hidden list at the site level creatively named "Taxonomy Hidden List".

But are they available for use in other list/libraries or only in list/libraries that they are defined in.

SharePoint transforms your enterprise keywords into a single, non-hierarchical term set. You can find this special term set, which is named the Keywords set, by using the Term Store Management Tool. It can be used in other list or library.


But I can also choose terms from Department or add new terms that eventually get inserted into the Department?

Only choose form Keywords term set and be inserted into the Keywords term set.

Don't understand your sentence. Can you reframe please.
